# How to update version of command processor (cmd.exe)?

Tags: windows, cmd

How to update version of command processor (cmd.exe)?

I've searched but I can only find stuff about updating Windows from command prompt and nowhere how to update command processor (cmd.exe).

Comment: Do you mean you want to change how the command prompt looks: **C:\>**.  You can use the `PROMPT` command to do that.

Comment: No i mean how to update the cprompt version sorry

Comment: You don't.  If Microsoft pushes out an update for CMD.exe then you will get a new version of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Upgrade to Windows 10**.

Versions of CMD are shipped as part of Windows.  To update CMD, you must update Windows.

Very occasionally, a change is pushed out to CMD via Windows Update, usually as a security or compatibility patch, but usually the only way to get a new version is to get a new version of Windows.

For example, my version of cmd is:

```
D:\>cmd /ver
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Version 6.3.9600 is also the Windows version number for Windows 8.1, which is my OS.

Answer (score -1):

> You don't. If Microsoft pushes out an update for CMD.exe then you will
>   get a new version of it. – Squashman 1 min ago